# Loop ansible playbook with different host

Tags: loops, ansible

I have an ansible playbook with several tasks on different servers

***main.yaml***

```yaml
- hosts: host1
  tasks
    - name: "Run in host1"
      unarchive:
      src: "{{ deliveryI }}{{ delivery }}.zip"
      dest: "{{ dir_app }}livraisons/"
      mode: "0755" 

- hosts: host2
  tasks:
    - name: "Run in host2"
      shell: xxxxxxxxx

- hosts: host3
```

The variable *delivery* is passed as an extra variable when I run the ansible playbook.

I want to loop this ansible playbook (main.yaml) with a list of delivery. For example, create a new ansible playbook that launches the main. Something like that:

```yaml
- include_tasks: "{{ playbook_dir }}/main.yaml"
     with_items: 
      - delivery1
      - delivery2
      - delivery3
```

Thanks for your help

I tried several solutions but they failed. I have a problem with the host. If I create a launcher I have to define a host for it. So I couldn't define host in the main with include_tasks.

Comment: At this stage and with so little information provided, the only sensible thing that can be proposed is a simple shell one liner: `for d in delivery1 delivery2 delivery3; do ansible-plabook -i your_inventory -e delivery=$d your_playbook.yml; done`

Answer (score 0):

The Ansible documentation provides an [example](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_loops.html#defining-inner-and-outer-variable-names-with-loop-var) of looping with `include_tasks`. You can override the name of the loop variable (defaults to `item`) using `loop_control`:

```yaml
- include_tasks: "{{ playbook_dir }}/main.yaml"
    loop: 
      - delivery1
      - delivery2
      - delivery3
    loop_control:
      loop_var: delivery
```